# How to prevent string substitution from inserting an additional backslash with Unicode characters?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

The double backslash here is causing me problems; how best can I avoid it?

```py
data = ('\u200e中國哲學書電子化計劃', 'latin')
'{}'.format(data)
> "('\\u200e中國哲學書電子化計劃', 'latin')"
```

Comment: You are formatting a tuple. Don't do that; the contents of containers are *always* shown as `repr()` in that case. Format *contents*.

Comment: See the section *"Container’s `__str__` uses contained objects’ `__repr__`"* in the first answer for an answer to this.

Comment: Very good, this gets to the heart of the matter. Why does `__repr__` replace the single slash with a double slash in `'\u200e中國哲學書電子化計劃'.__repr__()` ?